# asymptotic behaviour of a product

Tags: convergence-divergence, asymptotics

Suppose $a_j\downarrow 0,b_j\downarrow 0$, and $a_j/b_j\rightarrow 1$. Do we always have
$\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{1-a_j}{1-b_j}\rightarrow c$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ for some finite constant $c$?

Thanks!

Comment: If I didn't make a mistake I've a counter-example. You might want to check your proof while I write up an answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I made a mistake. Could you show me the counter-example please?

Comment: Give me a while I can't type LaTeX so fast.. But basically you stagger any monotonic sequence that converges to 0 and repeat each pair enough times so that the product blows up.

Comment: Oh I found an easier counter-example.. Give me a minute..

Comment: Ultimately the factors behave like $1 + b_j - a_j$, so convergence of the product would probably depend on convergence of $\sum_j (b_j - a_j)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counter-example:

Let $a_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+1}$

Let $b_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$

Then ( $a_k \to 0$ and $b_k \to 0$ and $\frac{a_k}{b_k} \to 1$ ) as $k \to \infty$

Also $\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1-a_k}{1-b_k} = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{k+1}^2}{\sqrt{k+1}^2-1} = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{k+1}{k} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: If you noticed I edited my answer because the first time I had made $b_1 = 1$, which already makes the question false. You could have stipulated $b_k < 1$ for any natural $k$, so I've shifted the sequence to satisfy that.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks a lot!